Special characters missing in MySQL database and displayed incorrectly in the browser whether in utf8mb3 or utf8mb4
I'm facing an issue with special characters (e.g., é, ç) in my web application.
Here's the situation:
My MySQL database, tables, and columns are all set to utf8mb4_unicode_ci.
UPDATE cars SET name = 'Cabrioleté' WHERE id = 1;

Issue in DB:
When I check the database directly (using the terminal or a client like MySQL Workbench), special characters like é or ' are missing. For instance, Cabrioleté appears as Cabriolet
Issue in Browser:
When I retrieve the data and render it in the browser, the character é displays as Ã©.
It's not only a é problem but it's the same with multiple special characters
Previously, my database and all its tables and columns were using utf8mb3_unicode_ci.
I was experiencing issues with special characters, where é was missing or corrupted, and rendered in the browser as Ã©.Since utf8mb3 is deprecated, I decided to migrate the database to utf8mb4
Migration Steps I Followed:

Dumped the database with mysqldump.
Replaced all occurrences of CHARSET utf8mb3 with CHARSET utf8mb4 and COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci with COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci in the SQL dump file.
Created a new database with utf8mb4 settings.
Restored the data using the mysql client

After migrating to utf8mb4, I still face the same encoding issues:
Special characters like é are missing in the database. For example, Cabrioleté becomes Cabriolet, and it's displayed in Browser with CabrioletÃ©
Things I've Tried:

Verified that the database, tables, and columns are now correctly set to utf8mb4_unicode_ci.
Ensured my HTML includes .
Confirmed that the dump file and all import/export scripts are saved in UTF-8 without BOM.

How can I ensure special characters are correctly stored and displayed in the database and browser?

It's most likely not a database issue, it's an issue of your webserver who delivers the page without UTF-8 charset. For apache you can set AddDefaultCharset utf-8. Or you can send the response header content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored -- "Cabriolet" is "truncation".   "Ã©" is "Mojibake".  Search for both terms in that bug report.

utf8mb3 vs utf8mb4 -- not the problem.  Collation -- not the problem.

Actually, I suppose there is a DB issue because in DB all characters are not correctly shown

The most likely culprit is your database connection encoding. You're never directly looking at the database, you're always using some client to connect to the database server. This client assumes some encoding for the connection it uses to talk to the database and interprets the received data accordingly, and vice versa. If that connection encoding is wrong, you'll get garbage somewhere; either on input or output. Since you're not telling us anything specific about what client you're using, that's all we can tell you.
